# Monoalphabetic Substitution Cipher

Tags: python, python-3.x, community-challenge, caesar-cipher

In light of [this months Community Challenge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5327/june-2015-community-challenge/5330#5330), I've taken a stab at building something related. Keep in mind, **this isn't a submission for the challenge, just a utility to help in the later process of completing the challenge**.

What we have here is your simple encryption and decryption (with a given key) tool. I'd like to know if what I have is the most efficient, the most well written, and the simplest form of these functions.

```
import random

alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

def encrypt(original, key=None):

    if key is None:
        l = list(alpha)
        random.shuffle(l)
        key = "".join(l)

    new = []

    for letter in original:
        new.append(key[alpha.index(letter)])

    return ["".join(new), key]

def decrypt(cipher, key=None):
    if key is not None:
        new = []
        for letter in cipher:
            new.append(alpha[key.index(letter)])

        return "".join(new)
    # we'll have an else here for the actual Community Challenge!
```

I'm nowhere near an expert with Python, so if I'm not following coding standards, please guide me there too.

A simple test might be:

```
e = encrypt("helloworld", None)
print(e)
print(decrypt(e[0], e[1]))
```

and we'd get something along the lines of:

```
['wussndnkst', 'qxvtupaweroslynzhkbigcdjmf']
helloworld
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` is just the constant [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase).

Whenever you have this pattern:

```
some_list = []
for dummy in some_iterable:
    some_list.append(some_function_of(dummy))
```

… that's a candidate for replacement with a list comprehension.

`alpha.index(letter)` and its inverse could be a performance issue when processing longer messages.  Making a dictionary for the translation table would be better.  Note that any character that is not ASCII lowercase will cause a `ValueError`.  For `encrypt()`,

```
translation = dict(zip(key, string.ascii_lowercase))
ciphertext = ''.join(translation.get(c, c) for c in original)
```

Here, `translation.get(c, c)` causes unrecognized characters to be passed through.  You can use `translation[c]` to restore the original exception-raising behaviour.

Comment: Oh excellent! I've managed to learn a bit more and fix everything you suggested. However, I don't think I understand how I could make "a dictionary for the translation table", could you elaborate please?

Comment: Added code in Rev 2.